# Variable assignment in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, variable-assignment

When I try following statements, it doesn't assign values properly to variables and loop goes infinite-

```
while ( [ $nos -ne 0 ] )
do
    rem = `expr $nos % 10`
    sum = `expr $sum + $rem`
    nos = `expr $nos / 10`
done
```

But when I remove spaces from left and right side of assignment operator, it works fine. Like this -

```
while ( [ $nos -ne 0 ] )
do
    rem=`expr $nos % 10`
    sum=`expr $sum + $rem`
    nos=`expr $nos / 10`
done
```

Why the Shell behaviour is like that?

Comment: As an aside, `expr` is a Bourneism, present only for backwards compatibility with 1970s-era shells; since literally the early 90s, the POSIX-standardized syntax for math has been `rem=$(( nos % 10 ))`, with only occasional holdouts (Sun being the most notorious) shipping noncompliant `/bin/sh` implementations.

Comment: ...you've also got some (lack-of-)quoting-related bugs; http://shellcheck.net/ will find those automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem = `expr $nos % 10`
```

Runs a command `rem` with its first argument `=`.

If it weren't for the POSIX sh standard requiring that assignments parse as a single word (which it does), one couldn't pass `=` as a first argument to a command or function; hence, the standard being written as it is.

---

There's further expressive power based on whitespace in assignments as well. For instance:

```
rem= foo
```

...runs `foo` with the environment variable `rem` set to an empty string only for the duration of that single command's execution, just as

```
var=val foo
```

sets `var` to `val` while running `foo`. This is useful syntax; if `var=val foo` were equivalent to `var="val foo"`, it would not be possible.

Comment: thanks Charles. I am just a beginner. Didn't know about this.

Answer (score -3):

In Shell script, you can create function. And to call a function, you just write

function arg1 arg2 ...

That's why, in my opinion, it works like this.

Plus, if you are using bash, you can do $((nos%10)) instead of calling the built-in expr

Comment: I don't think there is any relation in function call and variable assignment. Please can you elaborate

Comment: just watch the other comment then. The space is used as argument separator. So you try to call a function in your first exemple

Comment: `$(( nos % 10 ))` isn't just bash -- that's part of baseline POSIX. You might be thinking `(( ))`, without the leading `$`, as a math context; *that* part is a bash extension (or, rather, a ksh extension adopted by bash).

Comment: Nope, it is just that I dunno about POSIX since i've been only using bash.